# How do we create a array of 2 properties in yml?

Tags: ruby, yaml

How do we create a array of 2 properties in yml?

Eg:
Array of employees. Each employee has 2 properties, name and age

```
employee:
-name : emp1
 age : 20
-name :emp1
 age : 20
```

Is this correct?

Any finally i want to return it in ruby

```
def readEmployees
        [
            {name: 'emp1', age: '20'},
            {name: 'emp2', age: '30'},
        ]
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving a man a fish, I am going to feed him for a lifetime. You want to know how a structure would be presented in `yaml`? Check it:

```
inp = [
  {name: 'emp1', age: '20'},            
  {name: 'emp2', age: '30'},            
]          
inp.to_yaml
#⇒ "---\n- :name: emp1\n  :age: '20'\n- :name: emp2\n  :age: '30'\n"
```

---

For readers, the `yaml` above is:

```
---
- :name: emp1
  :age: '20'
- :name: emp2
  :age: '30'
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
employee:
-name : emp1
 age : 20
-name :emp1
 age : 20
```

is not correct YAML. For two reasons:

- you did not insert space after the dash that indicates a sequence element
- you did not insert a space after colon, before `emp1` in the second element (which is always needed except when you have quoted scalars: `{"name":"emp1"}`)

It is also not customary to insert spaces before the colon+space that separates the key from the value in mapping:

```
employee:
- name: emp1
  age: 20
- name: emp1
  age: 20
```

You should also note that there is no such thing as an array in YAML, nor are there  properties. A YAML sequence might be represented in Ruby as array and your properties are YAML key-value pairs that belong to a mapping.